# Query related to getting number of days in between of two days

Tags: c#

I need to get the number of days between two given dates.

I used *"(endDate-startDate).Days"* but my senior advised that it may incur some memory leaks, He told me that it may result in different values if used on a 32 bit system vs on a 64 bit system and advised me to use TimeSpan instead and then get the Days.

I couldn't get that point.

Can somebody please explain how it may incur any memory management issue?

```
DateTime dt1 = dateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = dateTime.Now.Adddays(-10);
int daysDiff = (dt2-dt1).Days; // I'm doing like this.

TimeSpan ts = dt2-dt1; // this is what my senior-
int daysDiff = ts.Days. // advised me.
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm not that proficient on this point. Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your senior doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: That is the exact same thing.

Comment: Your way of calculating days is better, because you don't create unnecessary variable to hold timespan.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the first version of the comments seemed more appropriate X-)

Comment: @astander - I decided to wuss out because I thought it might get flagged as offensive.

Comment: Sometimes the truth hurts

Comment: i think your senior needs to work hard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# code:

```
    int YourVersion()
    {
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
        int daysDiff = (dt2 - dt1).Days;
        return daysDiff;
    }
    int SeniorVersion()
    {
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
        TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
        int daysDiff = ts.Days;
        return daysDiff;
    }
```

Compiled on VS2013, Release build, decompiled IL:

Yours:

```
.method private hidebysig instance int32 
        YourVersion() cil managed
{
  // Code size       48 (0x30)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime dt1,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime dt2,
           [2] int32 daysDiff,
           [3] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime CS$0$0000,
           [4] valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan CS$0$0001)
  IL_0000:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
  IL_000b:  stloc.3
  IL_000c:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0000
  IL_000e:  ldc.r8     -10.
  IL_0017:  call       instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::AddDays(float64)
  IL_001c:  stloc.1
  IL_001d:  ldloc.1
  IL_001e:  ldloc.0
  IL_001f:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan [mscorlib]System.DateTime::op_Subtraction(valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime,
                                                                                                     valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime)
  IL_0024:  stloc.s    CS$0$0001
  IL_0026:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0001
  IL_0028:  call       instance int32 [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan::get_Days()
  IL_002d:  stloc.2
  IL_002e:  ldloc.2
  IL_002f:  ret
} // end of method Program::YourVersion
```

Your senior's:

```
.method private hidebysig instance int32 
        SeniorVersion() cil managed
{
  // Code size       48 (0x30)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime dt1,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime dt2,
           [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan ts,
           [3] int32 daysDiff,
           [4] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
  IL_000b:  stloc.s    CS$0$0000
  IL_000d:  ldloca.s   CS$0$0000
  IL_000f:  ldc.r8     -10.
  IL_0018:  call       instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::AddDays(float64)
  IL_001d:  stloc.1
  IL_001e:  ldloc.1
  IL_001f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0020:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan [mscorlib]System.DateTime::op_Subtraction(valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime,
                                                                                                     valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime)
  IL_0025:  stloc.2
  IL_0026:  ldloca.s   ts
  IL_0028:  call       instance int32 [mscorlib]System.TimeSpan::get_Days()
  IL_002d:  stloc.3
  IL_002e:  ldloc.3
  IL_002f:  ret
} // end of method Program::SeniorVersion
```

The difference? Yours has a compiler generated `TimeSpan` variable used to hold the result of `dt2 - dt1`, and your senior's has a named variable. Other than that, they're the same code.

There's no risk of a memory leak, and the code will run exactly the same on 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

(There are a few minor differences based on specific instructions used to access local variables, but these are not expected to produce any perturbations in the code the JIT can produce)

Comment: Pretty awesome answer :) I love "seniors" like this, I've had a few and It's a though situation to be in, but answers like this keeps their mouth shut :)

Comment: **Thanks a lot Damien_The_Unbeliever Sir** for such a nice explanation, I'm satisfied :)